# Init member of a model when it's first created

Tags: django

I have a model named `Calculation` that is connected to a `Measure` with a `OneToMany` relation. 
When a `Calculation` model object is created for the first time I want to initiate a certain dict. Later on I fill in the values and save the object.

The dict should not be created when the object is loaded from the DB
and should not be saved to the db until I issued `save()`.

I've red about Signals ([1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save)) and Factories ([1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/),[2](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes.html)) but i'm still a bit puzzled on how to accomplish that.

**models.py**

```
class Calculation(models.Model):
    measure = models.ForeignKey(Measure)
    modified_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    raw_parameters = hstore.DictionaryField(db_index=True, null=True)
    result = models.DecimalField(null=True,max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # init the relation
        super(Calculation, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # init a list of required parameters with empty values
        self.raw_parameters = dict((k,None) for k in self.measure.parameters.all().values_list('name',flat=True))
```

The way it is now is not good because it also execute when an existing object is loaded and it overrides the existing values in `raw_parameters`.
I've tried overloading a `create` function but it didn't work.

**Django newbi. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to override the "create" function of your model you have to override the `save` method when the instance's `id` is unset.

In your case the code would be something along these lines:

```
class Calculation(models.Model):
    # your fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            # your "on create only" logic here
            # ...
        super(Calculation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The "on create only" code will be called only when saving a newly-created object with an unassigned `pk`. Relevant docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will explain my self better - The `calculation` class offers some kind of simulation. I might work on the object for a while but end up not saving it at all, so i never actually issue `save`. is the `save` function called implicitly on object creation ?

Comment: Do you then need a Django model? Why not simply create a class instead?

Comment: Agree with @LaundroMat. Use model class only if you need persistence. If persistence not required use standard class and it's instances.

Comment: @LaundroMat,@Josvic Zammit - I might eventually save it to the database. Lets ask the opposite question - If I create a class I will have to map it to a calculation model anyway in order to save it, so why not use a model in the first place ? ... is it not possible to create an object without saving it on creation ?

Comment: @haki You can create a model instance without saving it to DB. But usually computed attributes (like the `raw_parameters` in your case) are computed just before persistence (i.e. the first time you save). That is the usual way; and instantiating models without saving defeats the purpose of inheriting from a model class. My recommendation is: use an intermediate "in memory" class until you need to save - once you need to save put the data from your intermediate "in memory" class into a model class instance and persist via `save()`.